# Spring Boot: different dependencies for IDE and package

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

What is the best approach to handle different dependencies trees for Spring Boot running under Eclipse (Spring Tools Suite)?
I'd like to run from IDE with Logback library enabled. And packaged version (uberJar) should not contain Logback because I'm using Log4j2 there. Build is managed by Maven.

Comment: You could use different [Maven profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) for this. Include Logback in one profile, and Log4J2 in another profile; configure your IDE to have the profile with Logback enabled, and build the JAR with the other profile enabled.

Comment: Ok, I can divide builds into profiles, but it's almos impossible to exclude logback from build with <exclude> tag, cuz its referenced from almost all spring modules. Can I remove it from resultinmg build somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, guys! I've combined your advice and config from [Spring docs](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/8f640c549f74256870b7e033170398a6103b2c61/spring-boot-docs/src/main/asciidoc/howto.adoc).
Finally I got:
`<profiles>
        <profile>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <id>runtime</id>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>build</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>`